# When is "ASP.NET web site administration tool" used?

Tags: asp.net

during web site design stage or when web site is running on production server?

Comment: I see it has users management features, which can be used after web site is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's used then it's during design stage to make some settings, create (test) users and roles and mix these two together.

Personally I don't really use it during development for customers as these applications mostly have to integrate with a legacy users database or something else like NAM. For these I simply create custom membership and role providers, plug them in, works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an asp.net site from scratch its a very useful tool to expedite your development process.

It can create an authentication system for you that ties directly into the login control available in visual studio.

I find it particularly useful for creating and configuring the .NET Roles and Membership tables.